# Are there any differences between the various editions of The Art of Computer Programming?

Tags: books

I'm trying to get my hands on a set of these books, and it seems the most recent printing was in 2011. It's currently out of print, and going for *crazy* money. Meanwhile older editions from the 70s are available on eBay for much cheaper.

Is there any reason to hold out for an affordable copy of the newer edition? Or are they exactly the same?

Comment: assume you refer to editions of named title.

Comment: The author keeps track of "Errata et Addenda" for each of the volumes of [TAoCP books](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html). One caveat though: it is in compressed PostScript or "raw TeX text".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same. The 1985 edition that I have includes RSA for example which wasn’t there earlier. Not sure about newer version.

Comment: Sounds like I'm getting the newest version, then